# Regex for non-continuous bit 1 segments

Tags: regex

Given a series of bits, e.g `10100011110010101` and `010001001010100`.

How can I write a regular expression to reflect the patterns where no 1s are neighbors?

For example, `010001001010100` is a good one, but `10100011110010101` is not as there are 1s neighboring.

**edit:**

**Sorry my above statement may be misleading. i don't want to check whether a sequence is non-1-neighboring. I want to use an regex to find all non-1-neighborings.**

Assume I have a very lone series of bits, I want to write a regex to find out all sub sequences where no 1s are neighbors.

Comment: How about simply detecting the undesired cases and filter them out?

Comment: Does that imply that the string shouldn't contain `11` _or_ (start & end with `1`)?

Comment: Are we talking strings of zeros and ones, or actual bit vectors?  E.g. 01000001 would be 0x41 or ASCII "A".

Comment: -1 for changing the question after receiving several good answers to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will match any run of zeros where any embedded ones are not adjacent to another one.  A leading or trailing one at beginning/end of string is accepted as well.

```
(^1)?0+(10+)*(1$)?
```

A test with your example strings yields:

```
bash$ grep -Eo '(^1)?0+(10+)*(1$)?' <<<10100011110010101
101000
0010101

bash$ grep -Eo '(^1)?0+(10+)*(1$)?' <<<010001001010100
010001001010100
```

Comment: They are very similar, but @hsz's answer was submitted before you changed your requirements, so it doesn't match the partial runs.

Answer (score 4):

Simply "11" will return true if neighboring ones exist.

Regards

Comment: Sorry my above statement may be misleading. i don't want to check whether a sequence is non-1-neighboring. I want to use an regex to find all non-1-neighborings.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with following regex:

```
^0*(10+)*1?$
```

Comment: @C.B. Ok, I've edited. I know that reverted regex will be simpler, but I give it as an example. :-)

Comment: To fix this for the updated requirements, if you change `^` to `(^1)?` and `1?$` to `(1?$)?` you get pretty much the same as mine.  The grouping is different but the basic idea is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `11+`, i.e. a `1` followed by at least one `1`.

Comment: Assume I have a very lone series of bits, I want to write a regex to find out all sub sequences where no 1s are neighbors.

Comment: @JacksonTale For example in `10100011110010101`, what should match then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if your regex flavor supports lookarounds:

```
(?<!1)1(?!1)
```

`(?<!1)`: not preceded by 1
`(?!1)`: not followed by 1

If your regex flavor doesn't support lookarounds, you can use a capturing group and 2 non capturing groups instead of:

```
(?:^|0)(1)(?:0|$)
```

*(Note that the capturing group is usefull only if you want to catch the offset of the capture with an appropriate function)*

Comment: It says true for `10100011110010101`

Comment: @M42: I know but the question has been edited. The OP "want to use an regex to find all non-1-neighborings"